# How to rewrite a URL with %23 in it?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a (wordpress) blog where after commenting the users are redirected back to the page with an anchor to their comment. Should look like this:

http://example.org/foo-bar/#comment-570630

But somehow I get a lot of 404 ins my logfiles for such URLs:

http://example.org/foo-bar/%23comment-570630

Is there a way to write a .htaccess rewrite rule to fix this?

Bonus question:
Any idea why this happens and what I can do about it?

Comment: @Gumbo: With a 302 Found redirect. The generated header looks like this: "Location: /foo-bar/#comment-571738"

Comment: Can you post the code that does that?

Comment: @Gumbo: Not really as it is burried deep in Wordpress core. In 99.99% of the cases it also works, and it isn't a widely reported Wordpress problem, so I think this is a dead end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%23` is the URL encoded representation of `#`. I suspect your rewrite rules will not satisfy `%23`. You ought to investigate how the response is being constructed. Specifically, any URL encoding functions.

However, it would be possible to solve your issue with a rewrite rule. Understand that you'll be returning two responses to the client after a comment is submitted. This is why it is preferable to correct the first response.

```
# http://example.org/foo-bar/%23comment-570630 -> http://example.org/foo-bar/#comment-570630
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} %23comment-\d+$
RewriteRule (.+)\/%23-comment(\d+)$ http://host/$1/#comment-$2 [R=301]
```

It's untested, but should work (I'm unsure about escaping `\%` as it has special meaning in mod_rewrite).

Comment: Problem is that the response is fine on all systems I could test it. It's # in the URL and the redirect works, I don't know where and why this could break.

Comment: To your rewrite rule: Doesn't work. The matching of the request_uri doesn't seem to work, that's where I got stuck and come here to ask, too.

Comment: `RewriteCond` isn't being satisfied? Have you tried escaping the percentage character?

Comment: Yes. first thing I did. I also tried to refine the RewriteRule with this online tester http://civilolydnad.se/projects/rewriterule/ and made it to `(.+)\/\%23comment-(.+)$ http://host/$1/#comment-$2 [R=301]`, but this also doesn't work on my server. Quite strange.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [B Flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b)?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} %23comment-\d+$
RewriteRule (.+)\/%23-comment(\d+)$ http://host/$1/#comment-$2 [B,R=301]
```

untested with your specific case, but used for a related problem.

Comment: this answer is for people googling for this exact same problem… apologies for kinda reviving this closed and old thread