# Rewrite an url with %23 to #

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried to do a bit of searching (and come up with this: [How to rewrite a URL with %23 in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438509/how-to-rewrite-a-url-with-23-in-it)) but its not quite what I'm looking for.

I have a website, with a tabbed content section (x-tab, y-tab, z-tab etc.). There are links: www.site.com/#x-tab. I then use jQuery to monitor whenever a -tab link is clicked and to display the selected content. This works fine.

Ive noticed a lot of 404 errors in my logs, pointing to www.site.com/%23x-tab, www.site.com/%23y-tab etc and so would like to rewrite %23*-tab to #*-tab (as it i want the x, y, z to be dynamic).

Would really appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using the `NE` flag, ie:

```
RewriteRule ^#x-tab / [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a little confusion here:
when you use `%23`  browsers send  this character as part of URL exactly. but when you use `#` browser doesn't send `#` and whatever is after that as a part of URL. so  `www.site.com/#x-tab` means `www.site.com/`  as URL (and be requested )but `x-tab`  as location hash. but when you use `www.site.com/%23x-tab`  browser sends that (exactly ) to server. And web server searches for file `23x-tab`  on server. 

So what you want is use `#`  NOT `%23`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Basically, i have a a lot of 404's in my server log where googlebot/bingbot are trying to crawl site.com/%23x-tab I get an email whenever a 404 is generated so I am trying to prevent these url's generating a 404. Basically i want requests for %23x-tab to redirect to #23x-tab